# XSLT: select a node who starts with a predefined list of elements

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

We have in input an XML like following:

```
<R>
   <MT N="folder" V="Folder1\Subfolder1" />
   <MT N="folder" V="Folder2xx\Subfolder1" />
   <MT N="folder" V="Folder3yyyy\Subfolder1" />
   <MT N="folder" V="Folder4zzzz\Subfolder1" />
</R>
```

In our XSLT that performs the display, the entry:

```
<xsl:value-of select="MT[@N='folder']/@V"/>
```

displays:

```
Folder1\Subfolder1 Folder2xx\Subfolder1 Folder3yyyy\Subfolder1 Folder4zzzz\Subfolder1
```

What we need to achieve is to select the unique entry who starts with a pre-defined configurable list of strings, e.g. if our pre-defined list is

```
Folder2xx, Folder18ppp, Folder212aaa
```

I would like to display as output only

```
Folder2xx\Subfolder1
```

The optimal thing would be even:

```
Folder2xx\Subfolder1 (linked 3 times)
```

but I would really appreciate help on the selection of the unique element.
That is unfortunately too complex for my knowledge on XSLT, can someone please help?
Our system supports XSLT 2.0 and XPATH 2.0

thanks a lot!

Mario

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short, 1-liner XPath 2.0 solution. :)

Comment: What is the logic behind the `(linked 3 times)`?

Comment: @Alejandro: actually the list of "folder" items is a list of real locations and links to them, so the (linked 3 times) is the number of elements who match the patterns of the real locations. Sorry it was not clear, but this was too me a really difficult thing to do, I didn't expect to have such a clear (and fast!) solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**:

```
MT[@N='folder']
     /@V[substring-before(.,'\')
        =
         ('Folder2xx', 'Folder18ppp', 'Folder212aaa')
        ]
```

Comment: @Dimitre: +1 Fast answer. I didn't see it. Deleting mine.

Comment: @Alejandro: Undelete it. It's not known whose one was faster :)

Comment: @Alejandro: It would be unfair that mine got an upvote and yours didn't.

Comment: @Dimitre: No problem. Yours was first and both looks equals: an existencial comparison against a sequence.

Comment: @Mario: I am happy it worked, Here at SO the established form of gratitude is accepting the answer -- this can be done by clicking the check-mark next to the answer. :)

Comment: @Alejandro: Do not opt out mate -- ypurs also deserves an upvote. Undelete it.